# How to solve the particular solution to a recurrence relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations

Here is my solution to a problem:https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eH7O.jpg, though the answer should be:`n+2/3` for the particular solution.

Where am I going wrong?

P.S. I am focusing on the particular solution right now. As that is where I am stuck.

Comment: How did you go from $$-10A+21B=0$$ to $$B = \dfrac{120}{441}$$
????

Comment: I first solve A, which is 12/21, then plug it in: -10A+21B=0 and arrive at B=120/441

Comment: Ahh ok. You're right. Let me see again:)

Comment: Please take the time to enter important parts of your question—most of the question, in this case—as text instead of forcing people who might wish to help you to chase a link to an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why are you taking it into differential equation.

Directly put $a_n=An+B$ into the recurrence relation.

$$A(n+2)+B-10(An+A+B)+21(An+B)=12n$$
$$\Longrightarrow 12An-8A+12B=12n$$

Comparing coefficients on both sides, we get,

$$A=1, B=\frac{2}{3}$$

as required.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Thanks, went back to the content I was watching and was confusing differential and recurrence. Using the wrong method and the rest is history...